# Ethereum Solidity Contract - Payable signature

Tags: ethereum, signature, solidity

in my solidity contract ERC20 I have a function that looks like this:

```
function buy() payable public {
    uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;                 // calculates the amount
    _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, amount);       // makes the transfers
}
```

Who should be paid in order to buy some tokens? Is the owner of the tokens minted? Also a normal "send" Ether to the owner of the contract would suffice to buy tokens?

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Who should be paid in order to buy some tokens? Is the owner of the tokens minted?**

As I know, all amount we send for buy tokens should be paid to contract itself. It means all ethers that sent to contract for buy tokens that are stored on contract and these ethers are used for buying or selling tokens circulation(if you provided sell option in a contract).

> [image]
>
> [image: another img for same topic]

Comment: I have the buy/sell option in the contract, although I thought the contract itself cannot hold any ether or tokens. Is that the case?

Comment: I added some images in my answer above regarding your doubt.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.